# Find point of systematic decrease in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1059.6, 1061.4, 1063.4, 1064.9, 1066.3, 
1068, 1069.8, 1071.4, 1072.9, 1074.4, 1075.9, 1077.5, 1079.1, 
1080.5, 1082.1, 1083.8, 1085.1, 1086.7, 1088.1, 1089.5, 1091.6, 
1093.1, 1094.5, 1095.8, 1097.1, 1098.4, 1099.8, 1101.1, 1102.5, 
1103.9, 1105.3, 1106.6, 1108, 1109.4, 1110.8, 1112.2, 1113.7, 
1115.2, 1116.5, 1117.9, 1119.1, 1120.4, 1121.8, 1123.1, 1124.8, 
1126.2, 1127.4, 1128.8, 1130.2, 1131.8, 1133.3, 1134.6, 1138.5, 
1141.2, 1142.4, 1143.6, 1144.8, 1146.8, 1148.2, 1149.6, 1150.9, 
1152.2, 1153.4, 1154.7, 1155.9, 1157.1, 1158.3, 1159.5, 1161.9, 
1163.4, 1164.7, 1166, 1167.2, 1169, 1170.3, 1171.5, 1172.8, 1173.9, 
1175.1, 1176.8, 1178, 1179.2, 1180.3, 1181.6, 1182.8, 1184.1, 
1185.8, 1187, 1188.2, 1189.4, 1190.5, 1191.8, 1193, 1194.3, 1195.5, 
1205.8, 1206.9, 1208, 1209, 1210.2, 1211.3, 1212.4, 1213.6, 1214.7, 
1217.2, 1218.6, 1222.3, 1223.6, 1224.7, 1225.9, 1227.1, 1228.2, 
1229.3, 1230.4, 1231.6, 1232.7, 1233.6, 1234.6, 1235.7, 1236.9, 
1238.4, 1239.5, 1240.6, 1241.6, 1242.7, 1243.7, 1244.8, 1245.9, 
1247, 1248.1, 1249.2, 1250.3, 1251.3, 1252.6, 1253.7, 1254.8, 
1255.8, 1256.8, 1257.8, 1258.8, 1261.4, 1262.5, 1263.5, 1264.5, 
1265.6, 1266.6, 1267.8, 1268.8, 1270.1, 1271.1, 1272.1, 1273.2, 
1274.1, 1275.2, 1276.3, 1279, 1280, 1281, 1282.1, 1283.1, 1284.1, 
1285, 1286, 1287, 1288, 1289, 1290, 1291.1, 1292.3, 1293.3, 1294.4, 
1298.6, 1299.6, 1300.5, 1301.5, 1302.5, 1303.5, 1304.6, 1305.5, 
1306.4, 1307.6, 1308.6, 1309.7, 1310.7, 1311.7, 1312.7, 1315.2, 
1316.3, 1317.3, 1318.3, 1319.3, 1320.3, 1321.3, 1322.3, 1323.2, 
1326.8, 1327.8, 1329, 1330, 1331, 1332, 1333, 1333.9, 1335, 1336, 
1337.3, 1338.3, 1339.3, 1340.5, 1341.6, 1342.7, 1343.8, 1344.9, 
1345.9, 1346.8, 1347.8, 1348.8, 1350, 1351.1, 1352, 1353.3, 1354.3, 
1355.3, 1356.2, 1357.1, 1358, 1359.2, 1360.2, 1364.4, 1365.5, 
1366.6, 1367.6, 1368.7, 1369.8, 1371, 1372, 1373, 1374.1, 1375, 
1376, 1376.9, 1377.8, 1378.7, 1379.6, 1380.5, 1381.4, 1382.3, 
1383.3, 1384.2, 1385.2, 1387.6, 1388.5, 1389.5, 1390.4, 1391.4, 
1392.5, 1393.6, 1394.6, 1395.6, 1397, 1397.9, 1398.8, 1399.8, 
1400.6, 1401.6, 1402.5, 1403.4, 1404.2, 1405.1, 1407.4, 1408.3, 
1409.2, 1410.1, 1411.2, 1412.2, 1413.2, 1414.2, 1415.6, 1416.7, 
1417.8, 1418.9, 1420.2, 1421.5, 1424.6, 1425.7, 1427, 1428.1, 
1429.3, 1430.7, 1431.9, 1433.1, 1434.5, 1435.7, 1436.8, 1438, 
1439.4, 1440.6, 1441.9, 1443, 1444.4, 1445.6, 1447.3, 1448.5, 
1449.7, 1450.9, 1452.1, 1453.2, 1454.5, 1455.6, 1456.8, 1458.1, 
1459.3, 1460.3, 1461.4, 1462.4, 1463.9, 1465.1, 1466.3, 1469.8, 
1471.1, 1472.6, 1473.8, 1475, 1476.2, 1477.5, 1479.1, 1480.7, 
1482, 1483.2, 1484.9, 1486.2, 1487.5, 1488.8, 1490, 1491.3, 1492.4, 
1503, 1504.3, 1506.3, 1507.5, 1508.8, 1510.2, 1511.4, 1512.5, 
1513.8, 1515.6, 1517.1, 1520.1, 1523.9, 1526.5, 1527.9, 1529.8, 
1531.2, 1532.4, 1533.7, 1536, 1537.4, 1538.8, 1540.2, 1541.5, 
1542.9, 1544.2, 1545.6, 1546.9, 1548.3, 1549.7, 1551.1, 1552.7, 
1554.1, 1556.4, 1557.8, 1559.2, 1560.6, 1562, 1563.4, 1564.7, 
1566.2, 1567.5, 1568.9, 1570.2, 1571.4, 1573.9, 1576.7, 1581.5, 
1582.8, 1584.7, 1586.2, 1587.7, 1589.3, 1591, 1592.8, 1594.7, 
1596.4, 1598.5, 1600.6, 1602.4, 1604.6, 1606.9, 1609, 1611, 1612.6, 
1614.4, 1616.3, 1618.6, 1620.6, 1622.4, 1624.5, 1627.2, 1629.3, 
1631.4, 1635, 1636.9, 1638.6, 1640.5, 1642.1, 1643.7, 1645.5, 
1647.1, 1648.7, 1650.9, 1653, 1655.2, 1657.1, 1659.1, 1661.5, 
1663.6, 1665.9, 1668.1, 1671.7, 1674, 1676.2, 1678.1, 1679.7, 
1681.6, 1683.6, 1685.7, 1688, 1693.7, 1695.7, 1697.6, 1699.7, 
1701.7, 1704.1), y = c(1.876, 2.027, 2.087, 2.231, 2.18, 1.922, 
1.921, 1.851, 1.961, 2.035, 2.043, 2.043, 1.838, 2.032, 2.112, 
1.976, 2.046, 2.117, 2.062, 2.07, 1.748, 1.917, 2.092, 2.283, 
2.158, 2.119, 2.023, 1.971, 1.882, 2.058, 2.141, 2.241, 2.079, 
1.946, 1.959, 2.117, 1.923, 2.015, 2.066, 1.98, 2.091, 1.929, 
1.987, 1.852, 1.935, 2.127, 1.982, 2.182, 2.099, 2.03, 1.912, 
1.998, 2.491, 2.359, 2.188, 1.965, 1.906, 1.772, 1.927, 2.077, 
2.381, 2.191, 2.089, 2.086, 2.017, 2.028, 1.832, 1.88, 2.053, 
2.177, 1.995, 2.045, 2.116, 1.961, 1.99, 2.227, 2.235, 2.208, 
2.249, 1.992, 2.045, 2.152, 2.237, 2.239, 2.247, 2.114, 1.956, 
2.042, 1.926, 2.396, 2.184, 2.208, 2.016, 2.177, 2.29, 2.469, 
2.502, 2.115, 2.081, 2.091, 2.188, 2.118, 2.179, 2.067, 1.962, 
2.181, 2.246, 2.526, 2.145, 1.961, 2.299, 2.306, 2.34, 2.133, 
1.974, 1.997, 2.47, 2.24, 2.247, 2.137, 1.965, 2.232, 2.225, 
2.417, 2.362, 2.155, 2.034, 2.151, 2.176, 2.183, 2.372, 2.145, 
2.284, 1.967, 2.299, 2.299, 2.183, 2.292, 2.193, 2.249, 2.32, 
2.333, 2.286, 2.216, 2.233, 2.453, 2.373, 2.284, 2.074, 2.014, 
2.153, 2.353, 2.465, 2.373, 2.181, 2.424, 2.334, 2.349, 2.39, 
2.513, 2.526, 2.268, 2.098, 2.326, 2.385, 2.306, 2.378, 2.126, 
2.191, 2.363, 2.222, 2.723, 2.686, 2.4, 2.251, 2.121, 2.104, 
2.16, 2.333, 2.151, 2.116, 2.136, 2.293, 2.281, 2.313, 2.374, 
2.585, 2.521, 2.656, 2.66, 2.399, 2.442, 2.413, 2.528, 2.212, 
2.58, 2.667, 2.153, 2.736, 2.486, 2.406, 2.39, 2.403, 2.504, 
2.502, 2.158, 2.617, 2.434, 2.364, 2.497, 2.456, 2.263, 2.432, 
2.562, 2.453, 2.249, 2.18, 2.141, 2.324, 2.176, 2.184, 2.153, 
2.332, 2.202, 2.332, 2.125, 2.156, 2.189, 2.71, 2.458, 2.502, 
2.285, 2.527, 2.437, 2.418, 2.507, 2.087, 2.321, 2.701, 2.486, 
2.389, 2.335, 2.26, 2.108, 2.164, 2.286, 2.103, 2.257, 2.137, 
2.076, 2.378, 2.637, 2.446, 2.448, 2.539, 2.253, 2.099, 2.59, 
2.405, 2.219, 2.542, 2.532, 2.507, 2.439, 2.463, 2.342, 2.329, 
2.436, 2.511, 2.557, 2.603, 2.5, 2.428, 2.204, 2.307, 2.174, 
2.193, 1.793, 2.116, 2.107, 2.209, 1.967, 1.834, 2.713, 2.647, 
2.379, 2.229, 2.11, 1.964, 1.985, 2.162, 1.996, 2.074, 1.994, 
1.839, 1.838, 1.743, 1.668, 1.91, 1.735, 1.714, 1.421, 1.767, 
1.816, 1.755, 1.755, 1.698, 1.608, 1.556, 1.511, 1.394, 1.425, 
1.579, 1.495, 1.627, 1.305, 1.471, 1.469, 1.67, 1.697, 1.42, 
1.483, 1.274, 1.341, 1.235, 1.295, 1.401, 1.463, 1.313, 1.176, 
1.333, 1.373, 1.299, 1.086, 1.139, 1.237, 1.303, 1.143, 1.13, 
1.114, 1.096, 1.248, 1.302, 1.19, 1.069, 1.1, 1.027, 0.897, 1.09, 
0.922, 1.116, 0.963, 1.011, 1.053, 1.025, 0.985, 0.981, 1.025, 
1.117, 1.141, 1.135, 1.068, 0.982, 1.028, 1.06, 1.004, 1.112, 
1.108, 1.04, 0.857, 0.91, 0.98, 1.081, 1.025, 0.996, 0.931, 1, 
1.074, 0.987, 0.996, 1.125, 0.9, 0.607, 1.17, 1.08, 1, 0.909, 
0.841, 0.924, 0.818, 0.846, 0.732, 1.006, 0.717, 0.594, 0.786, 
0.685, 0.619, 0.684, 0.69, 0.633, 0.564, 0.689, 0.555, 0.445, 
0.696, 0.677, 0.729, 0.541, 0.362, 0.312, 0.568, 0.711, 0.515, 
0.622, 0.583, 0.631, 0.645, 0.696, 0.535, 0.424, 0.469, 0.519, 
0.511, 0.485, 0.436, 0.412, 0.351, 0.556, 0.255, 0.519, 0.399, 
0.497, 0.477, 0.564, 0.462, 0.433, 0.616, 0.547, 0.42, 0.499, 
0.415, 0.368)), row.names = c(NA, -443L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("x", "y"))
```

**Plot:**

[image]

And I need to find the point that `y` starts to systematically decrease.

I know that the real point is `x == 1405`. However, is there a way to automatically detect it?

I am not expecting to find the exact `x` point. A really good approximation would do the job.

I already tried to perform a break point analysis with the **segmented** package, but with not much success. The best number I could get was `x == 1363`, but I am looking for a closer approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get a fitted smooth of the data using `loess`. When you say "starts to systematically decrease," I think you mean something like "when the slope gets negative beyond a certain threshold," since it seems to me that it visually peaks and starts to decline around the 1350's. I could manually get the peak to occur later by smoothing more than default, using span = 0.4.

```
library(broom)
fit <- loess(y ~ x, df, span = 0.4)
df_aug <- augment(fit)
```

Using that model, the peak looks to be around the 1370's.

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
df_aug %>% filter(.fitted == max(.fitted))
# # A tibble: 1 x 5
# y     x .fitted .se.fit .resid
# <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#   1  2.09  1373    2.39  0.0181 -0.307
```

I presume you could get a better result if you can more definitively describe what model should be used to define "systematically decrease."

You might alternately extract the slope and acceleration from the loess curve, but it's not clear that'd get you much closer you your expected result:

```
# Extract slope & acceleration
df_aug_slope <- df_aug %>%
  mutate(slope = (.fitted - lag(.fitted)) / 
                 (x - lag(x)),
         curve = (slope - lag(slope)) / 
                (x - lag(x)))


ggplot(df_aug_slope, aes(x)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted), color ="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y= slope * 100), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y= curve * 1000), color = "green") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1405, lty = "dashed") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: this is really nice! I am going to implement it